Are “your hearts” poetically portrayed as musical instruments in Ephesians 5:19?
Paul states the following in Ephesians 5:18–19 (NKJV, emphasis added):

And do not be drunk with wine, in which is dissipation; but be filled with the Spirit, speaking to one another in psalms and hymns and spiritual songs, singing and making melody in your heart to the Lord…

I know some people, interpreting “making melody” (psallo) to mean “play,” understand Paul as telling the Ephesians to play the “heart” as an instrument. Is this the sense the apostle Paul intends in this verse, or does “in your heart” have a different meaning?
Note: While “making melody” (psallo) does not seem to be synonymous with “play,” this question is about the meaning of “in your heart” specifically. I do not ask about what “making melody” means in the verse except where necessary to fully understand what “in your heart” means.
Related
Are musical instruments included in Ephesians 5:19?
In Ephesians 5:19, do "singing" and "making melody with your heart" have two different meanings?

What a nice observation! Actually, in Byzantine hymnology saints are sometimes referred at as "lyres of Holy Spirit".

Barnes' Notes on the Bible says it simply:

The word which he uses - ψάλλω psallō - means to touch, twitch,
pluck - as the hair, the beard; and then to twitch a string - to
"twang" it - as the string of a bow, and then the string of an
instrument of music. It is most frequently used in the sense of
touching or playing a lyre, or a harp; and then it denotes to make
music in general, to sing - perhaps usually with the idea of being
accompanied with a lyre or harp.


The idea here is, that of singing in the heart, or praising God from
the heart. The psalms, and hymns, and songs were to be sung so that
the heart should be engaged, and not so as to be mere music, or a mere external performance.

“Making melody in your heart” is generally understood to mean expressing praise to the Lord from within, from one’s inner being. The “heart” in biblical language often refers to the inner self, the seat of emotions and thoughts.
Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges notes:

in your heart] Both voice and instrument were literal and external, but the use of them both was to be spiritual, and so “in the heart.”
No other use of either, in and for worship, can be truly according to
the will of God (John 4:24).

And finally, the Pulpit Commentary says:

The great thought is that this musical service must not be musical
only, but a service of the heart, in rendering which the heart must be in a state of worship. Ephesians 5:19

So, it’s not so much about playing the heart as an instrument, but more about the heart being the source or origin of the melody. The music comes from the heart. Sincerity and genuine emotion.

As this answer makes clear, the verb ψάλλω (psalló) means in 1st century Koine Greek, "so sing": with or without accompaniment.
Thus, Eph 5:19 reads literally,

speaking to each other in psalms and hymns and spiritual songs,
singing and singing in your heart to the Lord.

The "singing and singing" translate two Keek verbs that have the same meaning; thus, to break the monotony, most translations render this phrase as either, "singing and making melody", or, "singing and making music".
In modern idiom, the last part of this verse might be translated as:

"keep a song in your heart", or, Sing in your heart", etc.

That is, maintain an attitude of gratitude and praise to God always.  Gill expresses it thus:

singing and making melody in your hearts to the Lord; singing, as it is a distinct thing from prayer, so from giving of thanks, which
is mentioned in Ephesians 5:20 as another duty; it is not a mental
praising of God, for it is called speaking, and teaching, and
admonishing, but it is a praising of God with the modulation of the
voice; and is rightly performed, when the heart and voice agree; when
there is a melody in the heart, as well as in the tongue; for singing
and making melody in the heart, is singing with, or from the heart, or
heartily; of as elsewhere, "with grace", and which the Alexandrian
copy reads here; that is, either with gratitude and thankfulness, or
with grace in exercise; and the end in view should be the glory of
God.


Thank you for your response! Just to confirm, your answer is “No” to the question of whether “your hearts” are poetically depicted as musical instruments, correct?

@TheEditor - in both ancient and modern idiom, the "heart" is the center of emotions.  Thus, "singing in the heart" simply refers to having a song in the heart but NOT playing the heart.  There is nothing in the verse about playing anything.

I think I understand. So my next question would be this: What does “singing in the heart” mean? Does it mean singing inwardly/silently or singing enthusiastically?

@TheEditor - it could mean either out load or silently - that will depend on the company and situation.

Thanks for your reply. According to the principle of “single meaning” in biblical exegesis, where a phrase does not mean two different things at the same time, would “in your hearts” in Ephesians 5:19 mean singing with heartfelt sincerity and devotion, rather than specifically “silently” or something else?

@TheEditor - I think that is reasonable - whether out loud or silently
